# Angular ui-select placeholder not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-select2, ui-select

We have been using ui-select (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) to theme dropdowns like select2. This functionality has largely been working apart from one aspect: default placeholders.

The code largely follows the ui-select demos (3rd example on this page: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview).

As far as I'm concerned the default text should be that of the 'placeholder' attribute. Instead, it appears blank until you choose an option. We have been using a hack whereby we set the value of the ui-select-match, in the Angular controller to counter this issue, but this is far from perfect and clearly not how it should be used.

```
<ui-select data-ng-model="producttype.selected" theme="select2" name="product-type">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a product type">
        {{$select.selected.title}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="producttype in productTypeOptions | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="producttype.title | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>                                               
</ui-select>
```

Has anyone ecountered this problem before, or have any idea as to what we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're disabling search this will also hide the placeholder even when there is no selection.

The placeholder span element :

```
<span ng-show="$select.searchEnabled && $select.isEmpty()" class="select2-chosen ng-binding ng-hide">My Placeholder</span>
```

Just removed the "$select.searchEnabled &&" in the template .js file and the placeholder will appear again.

As seen on by [hthabet on github](https://github.com/hthabet/ui-select/commit/d69dc3d52d7a049f27db3bc0ba593e66375d2f80)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when I had something else in the controller bound to the ng-model, like `producttype.selected`. The other binding would initialize the model and make the ui-select directive behave as if a choice had already been made.

If that's your problem, the `on-select` callback is helpful for binding the ui-select to another object, and then using merging the data you want back onto the original object.

Comment: Cheers. I looked into this, but this didn't appear to be the problem as I only had one model on the page at the time.

Comment: Problem i had was that the '.selected' variable i bound was initialised to {} which made the plugin think i already selected an item. I initialised it to null and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You will also run into this problem if the model you are binding to is part of an object and has a key/value pair where the key exists but the value is a null.

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.selectedItem.ID">....
```

And here is the object being referenced:

```
vm.selectedItem = {
  ID: null,
  description: null
}
```

This will result in a blank selection as well which prevents the placeholder from displaying.  I'm currently working on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bootstrap class "text-muted" that is assigned to the placeholder.
It has a property that sets the font color "white". So try to comment this property. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ui select doesnt work when search item closed or if the binding element is empty. The fastest way to do that adding css display:block placeholder item.

```
.select2-chosen{
   display: block !important;
}
```

Or you can edit ui-select.js.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the source code, you can do two things to fix it.

1. Turn on enableSearch like following.

   `$scope.enableSearch = function () {
          $scope.searchEnabled = true;
       };`
2. Or check what @TDing [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428264/angular-ui-select-placeholder-not-working-when-ng-model-is-initialized) or @Steve Ellis's answer on this post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the isEmpty check in select.js file.

just replace this check

value = ctrl.selected;
angular.isUndefined(value) || value === null;

with

angular.isUndefined(value) || value === null || angular.equals({}, value);